# Why is Insert.php returned when I click 'Submit'?

Tags: phpmyadmin, sql-insert

When I try to run Insert.php it returns the same code and does not proceed further, unable to understand what is wrong with my code or setup. I am new to the coding world.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

if(!$con)
{
    echo 'Not connected to server';
}
if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'tutorial'))
{
    echo 'Not selected database';
}

$Name = $_POST['username'];
$Email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO person (Name,Email) VALUES ('$Name','$Email')";

if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    echo 'Not inserted';
}
else{
    echo 'Inserted';
}

header("refresh:2; url=index.html");
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it returns same code"? You see your code in the browser?

Comment: I agree with @Makketronix, this isn't very clear. Furthermore, you have SQL injection vulnerabilities in your code - don't put this on the internet yet! Your database driver supports _parameter binding_ - please look into that.

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location:index.html");
```

Try This, I hope it will work in your code.